# Store heading and image tags in one table or in splitted tables for faster fetching in billions of data?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, indexing

How to store heading tags and img tags for billions of scraped pages?
I want to know is this better to store title and description in ex_contnet table and design a new table to store extracted tag for each page or I just use one table to store everything? (for faster fetching in billions of data)

Is this effective to design a different table for tags and keep relation of their parents to increasing the fetch speed in mysql database ?

I have a table like below:

```
ex_content
Column  Type    Null    Default Links to    Comments
c_id (Primary)  bigint(255) No           
cl_id   bigint(255) No           
cw_id   bigint(255) No           
c_title     varchar(500)    No           
c_meta_desc     varchar(500)    No           
c_img   varchar(255)    No           
c_heading1  varchar(500)    No           
c_heading2  varchar(500)    No           
c_heading3  varchar(500)    No           
c_heading4  varchar(500)    No           
c_heading5  varchar(500)    No           
c_content   text    No           
c_original_img_url  varchar(2000)   No           
c_servername    varchar(255)    No           
c_serverpath    varchar(255)    No           
c_logo_filename     varchar(255)    No           
c_profile_views     bigint(255) No  0        
c_popularity_score  bigint(255) No  0        
c_deactive  int(1)  No  0        
c_last_ex_date  date    No
```

I know that in many times we don't have any h5 or h4 tag in the pages and my question is: if store all heading tags in one table even when we don't have some of the tags and keep this columns null, in this situation we can get faster fetching or I need to design a new table (e.g. ex_htmltags) and store every tags that's exist for every page with keep relation to the parent row in ex_content table?

My spllited approach is something like below tables:

```
ex_content (some columns moved to ex_htmltags table)
Column  Type    Null    Default Links to    Comments
c_id (Primary)  bigint(255) No           
cl_id   bigint(255) No           
cw_id   bigint(255) No           
c_title     varchar(500)    No           
c_meta_desc     varchar(500)    No               
c_content   text    No                   
c_servername    varchar(255)    No           
c_serverpath    varchar(255)    No           
c_logo_filename     varchar(255)    No           
c_profile_views     bigint(255) No  0        
c_popularity_score  bigint(255) No  0        
c_deactive  int(1)  No  0        
c_last_ex_date  date    No           

ex_htmltags
Column  Type    Null    Default Links to    Comments
h_id (Primary)  bigint(255) No           
h_parent_id     bigint(255) No  // The id of rows in ex_content table    
h_original_img_url  varchar(2000)   No      
h_img   varchar(255)    No                
h_heading1  varchar(500)    No           
h_heading2  varchar(500)    No           
h_heading3  varchar(500)    No           
h_heading4  varchar(500)    No           
h_heading5  varchar(500)    No
```

Comment: If you don't query any of these things directly (e.g. `WHERE` clause on one of the columns or indexes) why not dump it into a JSON column?

Comment: Dear @tadman. you mean to add a json column and store all of this tags in this one column? is this better for fetching speed? if I need to one this tags I can use json_decode or something like this to access each tags, right?

Comment: You can do whatever you want with it, but unless you need to query individual parameters a JSON column is often more efficient. It's one piece of data to write, one piece to read, and normally JSON parsers are very fast. This also helps if your schema changes slightly, you won't have to add new columns.

Comment: Dear @tadman, It seems to be a good approach, but what about design a separate table or keep all data in one table ?

Comment: Storage of nulls is not going to be a problem. It all depends on how you are going to query the data. I assume you are going to need to do partial searches on all these pages - maybe a free text search? If you need to query, for example, where any header contains 'stack overflow' then its going to be easier if they are all in the one table. You could go down the json path but while json parsers may be fast I doubt very much they would be anywhere near as fast as a normal database/index lookup. Not something I've used though so happy to be proved wrong!

Comment: Dear @TomC, I want to know is this better to store all columns in one table or separate some tables that is not usable all the times in a different new table? I trying to get faster fetching. what is the effect of design a wide table (I mean a table with so many columns) for something about billions of rows? , I can spllite some columns to a new table. Is number of columns important in fetching speed?

Comment: One table is usually best until it isn't. Try the single-table approach at scale, load in lots of data, and see how it performs.

Comment: Dear @tadman Thank you so much for your comments, now I want to use one table for everything except images. my previous decision was use 4 table and separate everything but, based on your suggestion, I use just one table plus a table for images that's not good to use json for this image tags (because we have about 10 images individual by each row and we need to do regular update and I don't want to experience problem in query fetching speed).

Comment: Don't forget images, or large binary blobs of any form, and databases usually don't mix. These are much better off on a filesystem where backup and recovery is trivial. Also consider using an object-store database such as [Riak](https://riak.com) or a service like [S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/).

Comment: If you ever have a one-to-many relationship you'll want a proper relational structure to avoid violating the [Zero, One or Infinity Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_one_infinity_rule) of
[database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). Create a related table with an ID reference back to the other.

Comment: Dear @tadman Thank you so much for useful links and guidance. I checked the link of Riak and S3 and it seems to be very good services for my case. Also I checked the filesystem limitations. I have a relationship column in each table contain the id of their parents, I need to study about one-to-many relationships, I know something about proper indexing but I need to study about Zero One and infinity Rules in database normalization subject.